# iPhone + CSS3 Multi Col + Overflow: Scroll = Bug?

Tags: iphone, css, safari, webkit

all. I'm experiencing bizarre behavior while trying to achieve CSS3 multi-cols inside an overflow: scroll container. Works on Chrome + Safari for OS X, breaks on iPhone:

```
<div id="rubber-banded">
  <div id="columns">
    <p>[...]</p>
    <p>[...]</p>
    [...]
  </div>
</div>

#rubber-banded {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow:scroll;
  margin-top:42px;
  width:100%;
  outline:2px solid red;
  height:300px;
}

#columns {
  margin-top:10px;
  -webkit-column-width:120px;
  height:250px;
  outline:2px solid blue;
}
```

Here is the expected result: [image: expected result]

and here is the actual result: [image]

As you can see, the text overflows `#columns` until a new paragraph starts. Then, the next paragraph starts in the next column with a gap above. It's very strange, and if I change `overflow:scroll;` to `overflow:hidden;` on `#rubber-banded` I get the expected result—although, I don't get the rubber-banding effect I'm going for :(. I've also tried various combinations of `-webkit-column-break-after` to no avail.

Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property  `overflow: scroll` is interpreted differently by the browsers (although the browser engine is the same in your case), on iPhone every time when there is a `scroll` the browser adds a margin for the scrolls, because it is touch-optimized browser.

Comment: No matter the size of the `#rubber-banded`, its scroll margins (present on both iPhone and desktop webkit), or its overflow properties, **each text column always aligns to the top of `#columns` on Chrome + Safari**. We can confirm this by collapsing the height of `#rubber-banded` to less than `#columns`; Chrome + Safari add vertical scrollbars but columns render normally. iPhone does not. The behavior on desktop is that no matter what's going on around `#columns`, the text-columns should never overflow their container, and they should always align to the top.